# Features like fetching location while starting the Visit in my app working in some phone but not in other

Tags: javascript, react-native

trying to get location through this code

```
async function getGeolocation() {
  try {
    const position = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          resolve(position);
        },
        error => {
          reject(error);
        },
        {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000},
      );
    });
    const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
    const location = {latitude, longitude};
    return location;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error getting location: ', error);
    throw error; 
  }
}
```

When I/third person open the tab of startVisit in my/their app first time its ask the permission but in some of devices the start visit works as it fetch's the location but in some device its not.

using gradle version 7.5 and my build.gradle plugin is

[My android/buil.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRInl.png)

If an version issue of gradle plugin or anything please suggest.

Please help if this a problem of gradle plugin. Please Help`